# How to construct i.i.d. standard normal random variables on $\Omega=[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be the unit interval with Lebesgue measure on the Borel subsets. Can we find independent random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots$ defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, each normal mean zero, variance $1$?

Comment: When you say normal, you mean a Gaussian random variable?

Comment: Yes, this is a special case of a more general result (Borel isomorphism theorem), with a simpler proof. To start the proof, would you know how to define an i.i.d. sequence $(B_n)$ of bits, that is, independent random variables such that $P(B_n=0)=P(B_n=1)=\frac12$ for every $n$, on $\Omega$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can: this is Borel isomorphism theorem. Namely, you have a range space $Y = \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$, and some distribution $\mathsf Q$ over that space: in general it does not matter which as it will work for anything, in particular for your case of i.i.d. r.v.'s with zero mean and unit variance. The question is whether there exists a measurable map $f:[0,1] \to Y$ such that $\mathsf Q = \mathsf P\circ f^{-1}$. The answer is yes, but the proof is quite technical. You should start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space).