# Explicit construction of a an infinite-dimensional Gaussian Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

A [collection of lecture notes](https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Etsirel/Courses/Gauss3/lect21.pdf) for a course on probability given by Tsirelson, mentions that there exists an infinite sequence of independent standard normal random variables in $L_2(0,1)$ (with the Lebesgue measure), and it has to do with "tricks with binary digits".

Can anyone point out a reference where such a construction is carried out?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459230/how-to-construct-i-i-d-standard-normal-random-variables-on-omega-0-1-with?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know a reference, but it goes roughly like this.

Let $b_i(x)$ be the $i$th binary digit of $x \in [0,1]$.  (Values of $x$ with multiple binary expansions can be ignored, as they form a set of measure zero.)  Then the $b_i$ are iid Bernoulli random variables, see [How can I show that the "binary digit maps" $b_i : [0,1) \to \{0,1\}$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067585/how-can-i-show-that-the-binary-digit-maps-b-i-0-1-to-0-1-are-i-i-d).

Partition $\mathbb{N}$ into infinitely many disjoint infinite sets $\{n_{1,1}, n_{1,2}, \dots\}, \{n_{2,1}, n_{2,2}, \dots\}, \dots$, and set $$U_k(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i} b_{n_{k,i}}(x).$$
It is a standard exercise to check that each $U_k$ has a uniform $U(0,1)$ distribution, and that the $U_k$ are independent because they are constructed from disjoint sets of the $b_i$.

Finally let $\Phi$ be the standard normal cdf, and $\Phi^{-1}$ its inverse.  Let $Z_k = \Phi^{-1}(U_k)$.  It's easy to check that each $Z_k$ has a standard normal distribution, and they are independent because the $U_k$ were.

Relating this to [How to construct i.i.d. standard normal random variables on $\Omega=[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459230/how-to-construct-i-i-d-standard-normal-random-variables-on-omega-0-1-with?rq=1), the map $x \mapsto (U_1(x), U_2(x), \dots)$ is (almost) a Borel isomorphism between $[0,1]$ and the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^\omega$.  (I say "almost" because some sets of measure zero are left out.)

Comment: This is helpful, thank you!

Comment: ... so the series $\sum_kU_k(x)$ clearly equals $x$ for every $x\in [0,1]$. Hence for every $x$, $U_k(x)$ must tend to zero as $k\to\infty$, hence $Z_k(x)$ must tend to $-\infty$. Thus the sequence of gaussians eventually runs away to $-\infty$ pointwise. This is rather strange, is it not?

Comment: @uniquesolution: No, $\sum_k U_k(x)$ doesn't equal $x$.  Look again at the definition.  The power on $2$ and the (tiny, almost unreadable) subscript on $b$ aren't the same.  In fact, since the $U_k$ are iid, we have $\sum_k U_k(x) = \infty$ almost everywhere.

Comment: oh, yes. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Is it true that $U_k$ is independent of $Z_m$ for $k\neq m$?

Comment: @uniquesolution: Yes, certainly.  In general if $X,Y$ are independent then $f(X), g(Y)$ are independent for any (Borel) functions $f,g$.  This is very easy to check from the measure-theoretic definition of independence.

Comment: Thanks yet again!